# Applying recursive operation on a case class in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

I am trying to find an elegant way to do the following.

Let's assume we have the following classes:

```
case class Foo(fooName: String, bar: Bar, baz: Baz)
case class Bar(barName: String, baz: Baz)
case class Baz(bazName: String)
```

I want to be able to change the name (in this case of Foo and its children objects in some way), for example, to prefix them with some title.

I might define a typeclass which serves that purpose:

```
trait Titled[T] {
  def titled(t: T)(title: String): T
}
```

For Foo, the implementation would do this:

```
implicit val fooTitled: Titled[Foo] = new Titled[Foo] {
  def titled(foo: Foo)(title: String): Foo = foo.copy(fooName = title + fooName)
}
```

There could be other implementations, such as Esquired, which would suffix the name with "Esq."

But this does not update the title of the children values, bar and baz, which I would like.

What I'd eventually like to end up with is something like this:

```
//import all the implicits needed
val foo = Foo(...)
val titledFoo = foo.title("Mr. ") // names are prefixed with Mr.
val andEsquired = foo.esquire // names are also suffixed with Esq
```

Now, I've been looking online to see if it is possible to do, and I've seen shapeless library, but I'm still not on that level of Scala knowledge that I could decipher and create such "magic" if its even possible.

I am not necessarily looking for a complete solution (although I would appreciate one), but if someone could point me in the right direction, show me some examples, tutorials or whatever on things like these, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `def titled = foo.copy(title + foo.fooName, bar.titled, baz.titled)`?

Comment: Yes that would definitely work, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it along this reasoning: 1. title current instance of a class 2. title all other child fields for which exists an instance of a Titled typeclass

Comment: So, the function would return different results depending on what you imported? Are you sure you would actually _want_ that? :/

Comment: No, I'd have it not compile if there is no evidence of an instance of a typeclass for a field.

Comment: Well, that's not what you said earlier: " title all other child fields for which exists an instance of a Titled typeclass". Now you seem to be saying that _all_ fields must have such instance?

Comment: I apologise, I expressed myself incorrectly the first time.

Comment: Shapeless might be a bit heavyweight for what you want. Maybe just use implicit methods/classes to bolt on the extra methods, as described [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-add-new-methods-to-existing-classes)

Comment: I would just put an instance method in the case class. There's no need for typeclasses and implicit conversions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following type class. I assume that all case classes that should have type class instance have the first field of type `String` to be prefixed.

```
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons
  import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil}

  trait Titled[T] {
    def titled(t: T)(title: String): T
  }

  object Titled {
    //implicit def identity[A]: Titled[A] = new Titled[A] {
    //  override def titled(t: A)(title: String): A = t
    //}

    implicit def transform[A <: Product, L <: HList, H, T <: HList](implicit
      generic: Generic.Aux[A, L],
      isHCons: IsHCons.Aux[L, String, T],
      tailTitled: HListTitled[T]): Titled[A] = new Titled[A] {
      override def titled(t: A)(title: String): A = {
        val l = generic.to(t)
        val head = isHCons.head(l)
        val tail = isHCons.tail(l)
        val newHead = title + head
        val newTail = tailTitled.titled(tail)(title)
        val newL = isHCons.cons(newHead, newTail)
        generic.from(newL)
      }
    }
  }

  trait HListTitled[L <: HList] {
    def titled(t: L)(title: String): L
  }

  object HListTitled {
    implicit val hnil: HListTitled[HNil] = new HListTitled[HNil] {
      override def titled(t: HNil)(title: String): HNil = HNil
    }

    implicit def hcons[H, T <: HList](implicit
      headTitled: Titled[H],
      tailTitled: HListTitled[T]): HListTitled[H :: T] = new HListTitled[H :: T] {
      override def titled(t: H :: T)(title: String): H :: T = 
        headTitled.titled(t.head)(title) :: tailTitled.titled(t.tail)(title)
    }
  }

  implicit class TitledOps[T](t: T) {
    def titled(title: String)(implicit ttld: Titled[T]): T = ttld.titled(t)(title)
  }

  case class Foo(fooName: String, bar: Bar, baz: Baz)
  case class Bar(barName: String, baz: Baz)
  case class Baz(bazName: String)
  case class Foo1(fooName: String, bar: Bar, baz: Baz, i: Int)

  Foo("Johnson", Bar("Smith", Baz("Doe")), Baz("James")).titled("Mr. ")
  // Foo(Mr. Johnson,Bar(Mr. Smith,Baz(Mr. Doe)),Baz(Mr. James))
  Foo1("Johnson", Bar("Smith", Baz("Doe")), Baz("James"), 10).titled("Mr. ")
  // doesn't compile
  // if you want it to compile uncomment "identity"
```